# Why list comprehension with map() function in python can return None

Tags: python

```
>>> counters = [1,2,3,4]
>>> 
>>> [print(i, end=', ') for i in map(inc, counters)]

4, 5, 6, 7, [None, None, None, None]
```

Why does this code print `[None, None, None, None]`?

Answer (score 5):

Because `print` returns `None`?

So, the print is done (`4, 5, 6, 7,`) and then the list comprehension is returned (`[None, None, None, None]`)

What you want to do is use join:

```
>>> ', '.join(str(i) for i in map(inc, counters))
'4, 5, 6, 7'
```

or use the [`sep` argument of print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) (I don't have python3 right now but something like this:)

```
print(*map(inc, counters), sep=', ')
```

Comment: tks...well, what does the parameter 'map' function with the prefix '*' in print() function mean ?

Comment: @user2369034 It is used to [unpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) the list

Answer (score 3):

print is a function but it return `None` that's why you are getting none

Do this

```
In [3]: [i for i in map(abs, counters)]
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [7]: a = print(1234)
1234

In [11]: print(a)
None

[print(i, end=', ') for i in map(inc, counters)]
```

so when you do this `print` prints `i` **1, 2, 3, 4,** and then each time `list comprehension` return the output which is `None` hence **None, None, None, None**